# flair introduces empty spaces in string when doing NER task

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, flair

I'm working on a NER task using [flair](https://pypi.org/project/flair/). I noticed that sometimes flair introduces empty spaces after processing a sentence.

Example: the input sentence `Herman Melvilles email is mobydick123@gmail.com ;-)` gives as output `[PERSON_NAME] email is mobydick123 @ gmail.com ;-)` instead of `[PERSON_NAME] email is mobydick123@gmail.com ;-)`.

How can I fix that?

```
from flair.data import Sentence
from flair.models import SequenceTagger
import re
tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair/ner-english-ontonotes-large")

line = 'Herman Melvilles email is mobydick123@gmail.com ;-)'

sentence = Sentence(line)
tagger.predict(sentence)
ii = 0
sentence1 = sentence
if len(sentence.get_spans('ner')) > 0:
    for entry in sentence.get_spans('ner'):
        if 'PERSON' in str(entry):
            person = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', str(entry))
            sentence1 = str(sentence1).replace(str(person[0]), "[PERSON_NAME]")
     
            # Return the output sequence 
            try:
                sentence1 = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', sentence1)[0]
            except: 
                sentence1 = line
        else:
            sentence1 = line

print(sentence1)
```

Comment: "See below"?  Where?

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: It's certainly not flair that's doing that.  It's your code that's doing all the replacements.  You need to do some debug printing to figure out where you're doing this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that! I simply had to change how I extract the text between quotation marks. re.findall(r'"(.*?)"' fixed it.